# If $a,b,c>0$ and $abc≥1$, prove that $ \frac{a^2}{b} + \frac{b^2}{c} + \frac{c^2}{a} \geq \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a,b,c > 0$ such that $abc \geq 1$. Prove that: $$ \frac{a^2}{b} + \frac{b^2}{c} + \frac{c^2}{a} \geq \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}$$

I have tried Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $$LHS \geq a+b+c$$

And also: $$RHS \leq ab+bc+ca$$

So I need to prove: $$a+b+c \geq ab+bc+ca \Leftrightarrow (a+b+c)^2\geq(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)$$ (1)

But also I got: $$a+b+c \geq 3 \sqrt[3]{abc} \geq 3$$

So I want to change (1) into: $$(a+b+c)^2 \geq 3(ab+bc+ca)$$

I also think Schur and pqr method but they are to complicated

Comment: I added something another answer, if it works for you, I would be glad .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because by AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b}=\frac{1}{21}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{8a^2}{b}+\frac{11b^2}{c}+\frac{2c^2}{a}\right)\geq\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[21]{\left(\frac{a^2}{b}\right)^8\left(\frac{b^2}{c}\right)^{11}\left(\frac{c^2}{a}\right)^2}=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[21]{\frac{a^{14}b^{14}}{c^7}}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[3]{\frac{a^2b^2}{c}}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[3]{\frac{a^2b^2c^2}{c^3}}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{c}.$$
We can get coefficients $8$, $11$ and $2$ by the Weighted AM–GM:

> Let $a_i>0$, $\alpha_i>0$ such that $\alpha_1+\alpha_2+...+\alpha_n=1$. Prove that:
> $$\alpha_1a_1+\alpha_2a_2+...+\alpha_na_n\geq a_1^{\alpha_1}a_2^{\alpha_2}...a_n^{\alpha_n}.$$

This statement follows immediately by Jensen from the concavity of $\ln$.

Now, since $1\leq abc$, we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b}\geq\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{c}.$$
We'll try to find positive values of $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ such that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=1$ and the inequality
$$\alpha\frac{a^2}{b}+\beta\frac{b^2}{c}+\gamma\frac{c^2}{a}\geq\frac{\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}}{c}$$ would be true by AM-GM, for which we need
$$\left(\frac{a^2}{b}\right)^{\alpha}\left(\frac{b^2}{c}\right)^{\beta}\left(\frac{c^2}{a}\right)^{\gamma}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}}{c}$$ and we obtain the following system:
$$2\alpha-\gamma=\frac{2}{3},$$
$$2\beta-\alpha=\frac{2}{3}$$ and $$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=1,$$ which gives $$(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\left(\frac{8}{21},\frac{11}{21},\frac{2}{21}\right).$$

Comment: How can you know how to explain like that?

Comment: @Lục Trường Phát Is your question: How we can guess  coefficients $8$, $11$ and $2$?

Comment: Oh sorry! My English is too bad :( But how can you know that

Comment: I just used AM-GM. Do you say about coefficients $8$, $11$, $2$?

Comment: Yes, and also what is that method called? I never seen that before

Comment: @Lục Trường Phát It's weighted AM–GM

Comment: Do you have any pdf file about this? I can't find the same file in my language! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Wait. I'll  explain.

Comment: Can down-voter explain me, why did you do it?

Comment: How can you guess $\sum_{cyc}^{}\frac{a^2}{b}\geq \sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}\sum_{cyc}^{}\frac{1}{a}$ by adding $\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}$

Comment: @Lục Trường Phát It's homogenization. The LHS is first degree. We want that RHS would be first degree(in the starting form it's $-1$ degree.

Answer (score 4):

Applying the [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), you have :

$$
\begin{align}\small {\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{a}≥\frac {\left(\dfrac ab+\dfrac bc+\dfrac ca\right)^2}{\dfrac 1b+\dfrac 1c+\dfrac 1a}}\end{align}
$$

Thus, it is enough to show that :

$$
\begin{align}\frac ab+\frac bc+\frac ca≥\frac 1a+\frac 1b+\frac 1c\end{align}
$$

---

Finally, using the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM-GM_Inequality), we have :

$$
\begin{align}\begin{cases}\dfrac ab+\dfrac ab+\dfrac ca≥\dfrac {3\sqrt [3]{abc}}{b}≥\dfrac 3b\\
\dfrac ca+\dfrac ca+\dfrac bc≥\dfrac {3\sqrt [3]{abc}}{a}≥\dfrac 3a\\
\dfrac bc+\dfrac bc+\dfrac ab≥\dfrac {3\sqrt [3]{abc}}{c}≥\dfrac 3c\end{cases}\end{align}
$$

By summing up the inequalities side-by-side, we conclude that :

$$
\begin{align}\frac ab+\frac bc+\frac ca≥\frac 1a+\frac 1b+\frac 1c\end{align}
$$

which completes the proof .